Does KVL guarantee identical voltages/currents in similar circuits?
I have a question that is a bit abstract. Assuming I have two proper linear circuits, A and B, which have:

The same ideal components (for example, voltage source, inductor, capacitor, resistor)
The same number for each type of components (for example, 1 voltage source, 3 capacitors, 1 resistor, and 1 inductor)
The same value for each component (for example Vs=1V, L=1uH,C1=3uF, C2=5uF, C3=7uF, R=1kΩ)
Any KVL (Kirchhoff's Voltage Law) equation that exists in A also exists in B, regardless of the order (for example, \$V_L + V_C + V_S = 0\$ is the same as \$V_L + V_S + V_C = 0\$ or \$-V_L - V_S - V_C = 0\$)

Can we conclude that:

The voltage across each element in circuit A will be the same as the voltage across the corresponding element in circuit B?
The current through each element in circuit A will be the same as the current through the corresponding element in circuit B?

If this is not true, could you provide an example?
By proper circuit, I mean a normal circuit without contradictions, such as not having two ideal voltage sources with different values in parallel.

Have you read anything about the limitations of KVL? Wikipedia does an OK job of explaining

Also relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/685833/how-can-we-understand-kirchhoffs-voltage-law-from-the-principle-of-conservation

Imagine yourself running around on a hillside. You start and stop at the same point. Can you create a running track around that hillside where you don't end up at the same height?

Are the circuit topologies the same? If yes, then the 'same number' condition seems redundant, which suggests the topologies are different. Different arrangements of the same number and same value components can trivially have different voltages and currents (think voltage divider one or the other way up). If the circuits are completely identical, ie cloned, same topology, component values, then KVL is irrelevant, the circuits will obviously be and behave identically.

@MrGerber I just checked Wikipedia, and I think it's not related because it discusses lumped circuits and transmission lines, whereas this is specifically for lumped circuits.

@Neil_UK Are the circuit topologies the same? Assume that we don't know anything beyond the given assumptions. If they are the same, then there is nothing more to discuss.

@hana that should tell you something about in which conditions KVL has validity, and in which it doesn't. No reason to try and construct a circuit in the well known validity room of KVL and then ask if it KVL must hold

@MrGerber I think you misunderstood the question? I'm not asking if KVL must hold or not. I'm asking if based on the given assumptions of two circuits, would they have the same voltage and current for each corresponding component.

Maybe I did. It's a bit hard to decide what you're actually asking for.

How much do you allow to change the circuit topology? Of course if you have components in combinations of series and parallell and change the order of those, then you cant have the same potential over / current through them. That's obvious.

Just imagine the most different combinations of the two circuits you propose - one with one voltage source and all components in parallell vs one with one voltage source and all components in series. Of course they would not have the same potential over each component

@hana Your terms are loose. I think when you write circuit, you mean only the cases that are fully connected (the nullspace of the transpose of the incidence matrix has exactly one vector that includes all the nodes.) I think when you write KVL, you mean the minimum set of meshes (the nullspace of the incidence matrix) that are required. I think when you write KCL, you mean the edge currents connected to each node (except for two, and where those remaining two must be non-zero and of opposite sign) sum to zero. I don't want to write an answer because I want you to solve it on your own. But..

@hana Your 4th bullet pretty much nails down your question. You may want to read a few answers I've provided. They aren't directed to this specific question. But I suspect they may contain just enough to start you towards your own proof; if you set down with paper and pen and move columns and/or rows around in the incidence matrix by hand. See 1, 2, and 3.

@hana If you think closely about what I just wrote regarding fully connected directed graphs, "the nullspace of the transpose of the incidence matrix has exactly one vector that includes all the nodes", and then work to understand why and how it ties in with the other thing I just wrote wrote about two special nodes, "except for two, and where those remaining two must be non-zero and of opposite sign", then you will be hunting in the right direction.

@MrGerber I don't want to add any restrictions to the circuit. Any changes to the circuits are okay as long as they satisfy the 4 assumptions listed above.

@periblepsis I would like to include all possible connections, meaning some components may be floating. So, there are no restrictions on the circuit topology as long as they satisfy the 4 bullet points listed above.

@periblepsis  I'm reading your previous answer you linked, and I'll check if it helps.
Here is what I'm thinking: two circuits may have the same KVL equations (for all loops, including fundamental loops), but just having all KVL equations does not provide enough information to solve for voltages and currents. We need to use KCL as well. For example, in branch current analysis, we need both KVL and KCL, while in nodal analysis, we only need KCL. Mesh analysis is only for planar circuits, so that is not general enough.
If we can't solve for voltages/currents, then we can't compare them.

@hana I'm trying to push you into studying a high level view of linear algebra. It's easy to not be able to see the forest for all the trees. So there is a kind of assembly language view of linear algebra which keeps one from seeing well. And a higher level language view where one isn't mired in the weeds. Dr. Strang, recently retired, has videos at MIT and YouTube. He pushes on the higher level viewpoints well. I also want to push you towards directed graph theory -- particularly chapter 2 of Graph Theory and Its Engineering Applications by Wai-Kai Chen. You can make proofs either way.

The question can be answered trivially, once it's properly defined how alike the two circuits A and B are. The OP answered a question about the topologies of the circuits in a comment ...

Are the circuit topologies the same? Assume that we don't know anything beyond the given assumptions. If they are the same, then there is nothing more to discuss.

If A and B are identical, as in clones of each other, so copy one and paste to the other, they are trivially identical in every way. No need to invoke KVL, they are totally identical. As the OP said, nothing more to discuss. So they must be different in some way.
If A and B are not identical , but have the same component values, then the simplest counter-example that comes to mind is this. No need to invoke KVL, they are different by inspection. Consider the voltage at the junction of the resistors, with respect to either of the supply terminals.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
There is a simpler pair of circuits with only two resistors in a voltage divider configuration, flipping the top and bottom resistors, but that could be argued to be 'the same' with only a sign change in the power supply voltage.
(edit)
However, my two circuits above are disallowed by the OP's 4th bullet, all KVL loops are the same. I think this implies that the two circuits are copy/paste clones, but I've been wrong before on 'obvious' identities in topology and graph theory. I'm therefore reluctant to claim that two graphs (circuits) that have the same set of loop sub-graphs (KVL loops) are necessarily identical. I think a proof or refutation of this particular question is better addressed on MathOverflow.
(/edit)

This is what I was getting at in my latest comments.

The 4th bullet point says that any KVL equation that exists in circuit A also exists in circuit B. However, your two circuits don't satisfy this condition. For example, the loop with the 10kΩ and 100kΩ resistors in the first circuit doesn't exist in the second circuit.

@hana In that case I have missed the point. I think the 4th bullet implies the circuits are clones, copy-pasted, and so identical, but I'm not sure. If you think so, I suggest you write an answer to your own question. It might be worth asking the question on Mathoverflow, it may be a better fit there, as there may be some graph theory result about whether if two graphs (circuits) have the same cyclic sub-graphs (voltage loops for KVL) they are necessarily identical or not. This topological argument was too deep for me, and will probably be for most electronic engineers.

How could they be different then - it would be the same as asking whether KVL holds no matter where you start or which way you go around the circuit. As long as you don't change direction suddenly, and keep your polarities correct, it's correct.

How could we use the normal arithmetic operators if we suddenly decided that the axioms of algebra weren't valid? If we weren't able to order the summed terms around as long as we keep the polarity - how would the additive axiom and Rearrangement Property of Addition still work?

@MrGerber Can KVL be used to solve any circuit? I think so, and we just use other techniques on occasion for convenience. In which case, given that a circuit is solvable, we are able to define a sufficient number of loops to solve it, N equations for N unknowns and all that. I'm still not quite there on the graph theory - obviously two identical graphs will have identical sub-graphs, but I hesitate to assert the reverse is true. I was struck by how difficult it is to prove division by 3 works without assuming the Axiom of Choice, given that 3A<=>3B, prove that A<=>B.

I don't know anything about graph theory at all basically. I'm more thinking of it as if the OPs statement is that the two circuits has to have the same KVL equations, just ordered differently, then the rearrangement property of addition must make it such that it's impossible that a sum of terms in a different order, can give the terms different value

But then again, it would not be the first time I've misunderstood OPs question.

@Neil_UK It's an interesting problem but I'm not sure whether this question is the same as that problem.

Can KVL be used to solve any circuit? I don't think so. KVL and constitutive relations are not enough to solve circuits, you need KCL as well. For example, this one below, can you solve it with KVL and not any KCL?
https://ibb.co/q0S7JyK

@S.H.W I think  isomorphic concept is broader as it only cares about the shape not vertice namings.

@hana Directed graph includes both kcl  and kvl in the two null spaces of the linear algebra. Not one. Not the other. Both! There are four vector spaces in a circuit. It's beautiful really. Bullet 4 nails your question. You will see it if you practice moving rows and columns around. Just paper work. ComeS clear then.

@periblepsis Okay, I think I'll make new question to ask about some details which I'm not quite sure..
